# YouTube Data API V3 - value status.privacyStatus on private video

Tags: youtube-data-api

I'm doing the first tests with the new YouTube Data API V3 to migrate as soon as my site from old "API V2" to the new "V3 API."

I have the following problem: for a full request on a video id set as "private" as:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=7J7tGINYazA&key=**************************&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status

the result is the following:

```
{  
  "kind", "youtube # videoListResponse"
  "etag": "\" yHwg34KvgIlW9-uBcSEkgasDbzI / T_9s-xed4wEGn3XBIbu1JsPGi2U \ "",
  "PageInfo": {
   "totalResults": 0,
   "resultsPerPage": 0
  },
  "items": []
}
```

as in the case of a video that does not exist ...

but according to what reported in the literature:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#status.privacyStatus

should not be returned an sippet containing the status of the private video like this:

```
{
  "kind", "youtube # videoListResponse"
  "etag": "\" yHwg34KvgIlW9-uBcSEkgasDbzI / ULL6GjWjIQ4a7ruFwiAk1ExdLiw \ "",
  "PageInfo": {
   "totalResults": 1,
   "resultsPerPage": 1
  },
  "items": [
   {
    "kind", "youtube video #"
    "etag": "\" yHwg34KvgIlW9-uBcSEkgasDbzI / CWIAg26CY5tX532HpkYrib52e0c \ "",
    "id": "nemioqnQa0Y"
    "status": {
     "uploadStatus": "processed"
     "privacyStatus": "private"
     "license": "youtube"
     "embeddable": false,
     "publicStatsViewable": false
    }
   }
  ]
}
```

The parameter privacyStatus should not contain 3 possible values (private, public, unlisted), as indicated in the documentation?

How in the world does not return the value "private"? ... Is this a bug?

Can you help? thanks

Comment: Hello can i get your method of uploading i am trying it from 3 days but didn't get any success.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the video is private. Using the api key, anyone can request any video if they know the id. However, since your video is set to private, you would need to use OAuth to authenticate.

Another way to think of it is like this - If I somehow gained access to your private video ID, perhaps I just got lucky and picked a random made-up id and got yours, I still should not be able to view it just because I know the id, and have a key - I would need to authenticate first to prove to YouTube that I am the owner of that private video.